# Cpu Compatability

Tags: cpu, motherboard

I currently own a ASROCK ConRoe945G-DVI Motherboard, and am wondering if it will support a "Wolfdale" Core 2 Duo CPU

Its a fairly old motherboard, and the company website only lists the "Conroe" CPU's as compatable, however My understanding is that both the Conroe/Wolfdale CPU's are socket LGA 775.

I was hoping to fit something like a E8400 Core 2 Duo, will this work.

Here is the link to the MB site:

http://www.asrock.com/mb/overview.asp?Model=CONROE945G-DVI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CPU support page specifically states Wolfdale CPUs are not supported. Wolfdale CPUs are based on 45nm lithography as compared to Conroe's 65nm. ALso, they run at a FSB speed of 1333 MHz, while the Conroe runs at 1066 MHz.

So, no E8400 will not work.

Here's a [comparison](http://ark.intel.com/Compare.aspx?ids=27250,33910,) of the Conroe against the Wolfdale processor.

Answer (score 0):

My 945G-DVI with the latest firmware supports a E8400 fine.

Possibly a firmware upgrade wasn't available when the question was asked.

It doesn't support quads like my Q6600 however.